# iBeacon: notifyOnEntry=NO and notifyOnExit=NO,but delegate is being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

my code:

```
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:UUID identifier:@"com.dtha.ibeacon"];
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = NO;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = NO;
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

but delegate's method:
`locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and `locationManager:didExitRegion:` is being called when I entry the region and exits the region ,I don't know what the role of `notifyOnEntry` and `notifyOnExit`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
```

With `.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` set to `YES` the delegate is called when beacon is turned on.

Also

```
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

should not be used as it will call delegate again when exiting a beacon region.

I suggest you to use instead:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion]
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion]
```

Comment: But even if I remove self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES and [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion] code,delegate is still be called,I want to know what's the meaning of  self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = NO and self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = NO    I think I set these properties to NO, the delegate should not be called.